# IIS Disable the use of web.config

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

For some reason when I make a change to IIS 7 now it generates a web.config file for things like mime types and directory browsing.  I do not remember every seeing this behavior from IIS before so I am wondering how I can turn it off.  I do not want the web.config file to be generated much less used in the site I am developing for IIS.   Please advise as to disable this and force IIS to make these changes without generating the web.config.
Thanks in advance,
Ed

Comment: At an application level, IIS' settings are stored in the web.config file, that's just how it works. What kind of site are you hosting in IIS that doesn't need a web.config file? What's the harm in having it other than "I do not want the web.config file"? IIS is configured to never serve *.config files, so there's no security issues.

Answer (score -1):

Since IIS 7.0 the IIS has started to store the settings in web.config. which is very handy if you are going to change the hosting of your domain. All of your application level settings will remain in one place.

If you are a developer, the web.config can perform a lot of things that can ease your life. There is no harm in keeping this file on server.